# how do i check whether an ufw rule is reboot-safe?

Tags: firewall, ufw

So I have just added a firewall rule using ufw. How do I know whether I have to do additional steps to make this rule also automatically present after reboot?

(2nd question, but less important to me: If they are needed, which steps?)

For example: Do I have to check for installed/enabled/configured iptables-save? Do I have to put the rule into /etc/ufw/? (where?) Is there a rule like: If I am using Ubuntu, then ufw will always remeber state after reboot?

I am not used to work with ufw or iptables-save. I just read rumors in forums and the man page for ufw.

If you have to assume an operating system for your answer then please assume Ubuntu 16.04.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

ufw doesn't make a distinction between the running state of the firewall and the permanent saved state. All rule changes take effect immediately and are persistent.

Comment: Thanks! Do you have a trustable source for this information or do I have to trust you?

Comment: You could read the man page, or the source code, or simply gain experience with it. Any of these would suffice.

Answer (score 1):

This page was returned to me when troubleshooting a firewall problem in Ubuntu 20.04 after boot - I was lucky to get inbound ssh, but no outgoing connection was possible. Everything was working before reload, thus my setup was clearly not reboot safe.

Iptables were showing incomplete ruleset, and it took some time to figure out the situation. This hint was found in the logs:

```
Feb 16 20:22:39 hostname ufw-init[512]: iptables-restore v1.8.4 (legacy): no command specified
Feb 16 20:22:39 hostname ufw-init[512]: Error occurred at line: 18
Feb 16 20:22:39 hostname ufw-init[512]: Try `iptables-restore -h' or 'iptables-restore --help' for more information.
Feb 16 20:22:39 hostname ufw-init[586]: Problem running '/etc/ufw/before.rules'
```

What actually happened: in the past I added some special entries into /etc/ufw/before.rules to limit number of new connections from source per timeframe using `recent` module.

The rules themselves were tested with iptables, but the line 18 contained one single space and this was sufficient for iptables-restore to fail and for ufw to break - leaving incomplete ruleset in place.

This could be seen as a bug with iptables-restore, empty lines are in the file already and a space is difficult to spot. At the other hand the files created with iptable-save are not expected to be edited manually. Here they are created by ufw and it is advised to update them in some situations.

To the question: My ufw setup was clearly not reboot-safe, but there was no clear way to verify/validate it with a remote system. I ended up with rsyncing the boot and root partitions to a local virtual machine. Checking the outcome locally provided the confidence that after reboot all services shall work and I will be able to connect.